# Solve the integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, random-variables, exponential-function

Can anyone solve these two integrals .

$$ \int_{0}^{ \infty }   \frac{x^2 e^{-x^2/2 \sigma ^2}}{(x-a)^2+b^2}  dx $$

and

$$ \int_{0}^{ \infty }   \frac{e^{-(\ln x - \mu )^2/2 \sigma ^2}}{(x-a)^2+b^2}  dx $$

Either give me some hint or tell me the procedure, if anybody knows how to solve these type of exponential integrals.

Thanks

Comment: Mathematica can find the first integral in terms of the exponential integral special function.

Comment: it's gonna be a little bit messy to get a closed form solution, but it's in principle doable. Maybe tomorrow i find the time

Comment: can you tell me which procedure to use .. in order to solve this integral

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that $a$ and $b$ are both real numbers and that $b \neq 0$. Then the function $\frac{z^{2}e^{-z^{2}/\sigma^{2}}}{(z-a)^{2} + b^{2}}$ for complex-valued $z$ is meromorphic with poles at $z = a \pm bi$.

Then my idea would be to try integrating over a quarter pie-slice contour: $\Gamma_{R} = [0,R] \cup i[0,R] \cup \{ Re^{i\theta} \, : \, \theta \in [0,\pi/2]\}$, oriented counter-clockwise. Then apply the Cauchy residue formula, and if one can show the integrals over the second and third components of $\Gamma_{R}$ go to zero as $R \to \infty$, we are done.

Comment: $$e^{-(i t)^2/\sigma^2} = e^{t^2/\sigma^2}$$